# How do I get rid of my unchecked warning on implicit class with higher order function

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write an auto-retrying transaction "monkey patch" on top of slick (1.0, unfortunately).  In addition, i want it to only retry on certain types of exceptions.  Unfortunately, I keep running issues of type erasure.  From what I understand, what im trying to do is im ending up mixing runtime and compile time idioms, but at this point, im all out of ideas.  Do i try using reflection?

```
object SessionSupport {

  /**
   * Patches the session object to add trnansaction serializable
   * with automatic retry
   */
  implicit class SlickSessionWrapper(session:Session) {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

    val MAX_RETRIES = 3
    // UNFORTUNATELY I CANT SEEM TO GET RID OF THE UNCHECKED WARNING.
    // As such, the type check is alwasy going to "pass" for ANY throwable
    def withRetryingSerializableTransaction[A, T <: Throwable ](f: => A)(implicit retryCt:Int = 0):A = {
      val res:Try[A] = session.withTransaction {
        session.conn.setTransactionIsolation(
          java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE
        )

        Try(f)
      }

      res match {
        case Success(v) => v
        case Failure(thr) => {
          if(thr.isInstanceOf[T] && retryCt < MAX_RETRIES) {  // type erasure here!!!
            logger.debug(s"Caught ${thr.toString}, retrying")
            withRetryingSerializableTransaction[A, T](f)(retryCt + 1)
          } else {
            logger.error(s"Caught ${thr.toString}.  Rethrowing", thr)
            throw thr
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need reflection for this. 
Change the declaration to

```
def withRetryingSerializableTransaction[A, T <: Throwable : Manifest]
```

and then, instead of `thr.isInstanceOf[T]`, do `manifest.runtimeClass.isInstance(thr)`

Comment: yes! this works.  Separate question, will this work for TypeTags and ClassTags as well?

Comment: Well, `Manifest` _is_ a `ClassTag`, so, yes, it'll work. It is actually, probably, better to use `ClassTag` instead of `Manifest`, because manifests are going to get deprecated soon. `TypeTag` is a somewhat different beast. You could make it work here, but it is more complicated, and not necessary for this use case.